# solidity | mocha | address is not a contract

Tags: mocha.js, ethereum, solidity

I am trying to run below code in mocha. I am using rinkeby network.
As you can see in the [etherscan address](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xe950a05cc194a83a11533bf18218355b21e315ba) `0xe950a05cc194a83a11533bf18218355b21e315ba` is a contract but when I call getRequestsCount method i am getting the error as address is not a contact. Could someone please help me.

```
const campaign = new web3.eth.Contract(
    JSON.parse(compiledCampaign.interface),
    '0xe950a05cc194a83a11533bf18218355b21e315ba'
);
const summary = campaign.methods.getRequestsCount().call();
console.log(summary);
```

> Error:
>   Attempting to run transaction which calls a contract function, but recipient address 0xe950a05cc194a83a11533bf18218355b21e315ba is not a contract address

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
// Initialize contract variable with contract ABI
const campaign = new web3.eth.Contract(
    JSON.parse(compiledCampaign.interface)
);

// Get contract at the contract address
campaignContract = campaign.at('0xe950a05cc194a83a11533bf18218355b21e315ba');

const summary = campaignContract.getRequestsCount().call();
```

Comment: Great. Kindly go ahead and upvote + accept my answer if it helped you.